# Sub categories of products in WooCommerce plugin in WordPress are not displaying on UI?

Tags: php, plugins, woocommerce

Categories of products are displaying on webpage successfully.
But sub categories are not displayed on page.
I have checked all the conditions in Catalog section in admin panel.
Please suggest me the solution for it.
I am using WooCommerce plugin in WordPress in php.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. First choose the subcategory for any product. Then categories or subcategories are being displayed.
Then in nav menu of Menus option in Appearance, add the subcategories to the nav menu of categories. Please make sure sub categories would be dragged in parent-child relation. It would be as like in menus :
                        Parent 1
                            Child 1
                        Parent 2

Then, sub categories will be displayed. Sub categories should have in parents in the category panel of products panel of woocommerce plugin.